# Customized picklist values for each record

Tags: picklist

I basically want to know if < Assigning customized picklist values for each record of a custom object > is technically possible.

It's not about record types, it's about a single record having personally customized picklist values.

e.g. account A has [A, B, C] in its < Alphabet > picklist while account B has [D, E, F] in the same object.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anything's possible. What's your budget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create picklist field for the same
2. Then for record A and B identify a picklist field such that anypoint the value will be different for both the records and be consistent.
3. Then make the newly created picklist field dependent on the picklist field identified in the second step